open opposite position immediately after hit SL issue in mql4
When a certain buy condition is met, I want to open a buy position and set the take profit (TP) and stop loss (SL) based on the candle length.
I found a Martingale strategy on Forex Factory that is similar to what I want. The main function of this Martingale strategy is that when a buy position hits the SL, it opens an opposite sell position with 2x the lot size.
It is working, but it does not open the sell position immediately once the buy position hits the SL.
Here is the code I modified, but it still does not open immediately.
Any help would be much appreciated!
double barLength = High[1] - Low[1];
           if(OrderType() == OP_BUY) {
              if(OrderOpenPrice() > OrderClosePrice()) {
                 SendOrder(Symbol(), OP_SELL, OrderLots() * multiply, Bid, 3, Bid + barLength, Bid - barLength, "martingale sell", magic, Red);
              } else {
                 SendOrder(Symbol(), OP_BUY, lotes, Ask, 3, Ask - barLength, Ask + barLength, "martingale buy", magic, Blue);
              }

and here is full code.
#property copyright "Copyright 2015, Tomas RD"
#property link      "https://www.mql5.com"
#property version   "1.01"
#property strict

int MagicNumber=1;
extern int magic=3059823;
extern double lotes=0.01;
extern bool UseRisk = FALSE;
extern double Risk = 0.1; 
extern double stop_loss=30;
extern double take_profit =30;
extern double multiply=2.5;
extern string INDICATOR_PARAMETER1 ="=========Candle==========";
extern int SHIFT_CANDLE=1;
double lots=0.01;
int TP=20;
int SL=20;

extern string INDICATOR_PARAMETER2 ="=========Volumes==========";
extern int SHIFT_VOLUME=1;
double Scale, stop_loss_v, take_profit_v;
int LOTS, x, f, g, h, k, y, z, jumlahbuy, jumlahbuylimit, jumlahselllimit, jumlahsell, jumlahbuystop, jumlahsellstop;
double BUY[99], SELL[99], BUYLIMIT[99], SELLLIMIT[99], BUYSTOP[99], SELLSTOP[99], BATAS;
int prec=0;
int a=0;
double pt, i, minlot, stoplevel;
color FontColorUp1 = Red;  
color FontColorDn1 = White; 
color FontColor = Blue;
color FontColorUp2 = Yellow;  
color FontColorDn2 = Lime; 
color FontUP = Lime;  
color Font = White; 
color FontDOWN = Red; 

double initialBarLength = 0;
bool buyConditionMet = false;

int OnInit() {
   switch(Digits) {
      case 1: Scale = 0.1; break;
      case 2: Scale = 0.01; break;
      case 3: Scale = 0.01; break;
      case 4: Scale = 0.0001; break;
      case 5: Scale = 0.0001; break;
   }
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}

void OnDeinit(const int reason) {
   for(int i=1; i<=50; i++) {
      ObjectDelete("Market_Price_Label" + IntegerToString(i));
   }
}

void OnTick() {
   if(lotesMarginFree() >= MarketInfo(NULL, MODE_MINLOT)) {
      if (UseRisk == TRUE) lotes = (AccountFreeMargin() / 10000) * Risk;
      if(vol_ea() == 1 ) {
         initialBarLength = High[1] - Low[1];
         //buyConditionMet = true/
         OpenMartingale();
      }
   }
   modifyOrders();
}

void modifyOrders() {
   double tp, sl;
   for(int i=OrdersTotal()-1; i>=0; i--) {
      if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_OPEN)) {
         if(OrderMagicNumber() == magic) {
            if(buyConditionMet) {
               double barLength = initialBarLength;

               if(OrderType() == OP_BUY) {
                  sl = OrderOpenPrice() - barLength;
                  tp = OrderOpenPrice() + barLength;
               }
               if(OrderType() == OP_SELL) {
                  sl = OrderOpenPrice() + barLength;
                  tp = OrderOpenPrice() - barLength;
               }

               sl = NormalizeDouble(sl, Digits);
               tp = NormalizeDouble(tp, Digits);

               if(OrderTakeProfit() == 0 && OrderStopLoss() == 0) {
                  int p = OrderModify(OrderTicket(), OrderOpenPrice(), sl, tp, 0);
                  if (p == 0) {
                     Print("OrderModify failed with error #", GetLastError());
                  }
               }

               if(OrderType() == OP_BUY && Bid <= sl) {
                  OrderClose(OrderTicket(), OrderLots(), Bid, 3, clrRed);
                  SendOrder(Symbol(), OP_SELL, OrderLots(), Bid, 3, Bid + barLength, Bid - barLength, "Opposite sell", magic, Red);
               }
               if(OrderType() == OP_SELL && Ask >= sl) {
                  OrderClose(OrderTicket(), OrderLots(), Ask, 3, clrBlue);
                  SendOrder(Symbol(), OP_BUY, OrderLots(), Ask, 3, Ask - barLength, Ask + barLength, "Opposite buy", magic, Blue);
               }

               if(OrderType() == OP_BUY && Bid >= tp) {
                  OrderClose(OrderTicket(), OrderLots(), Bid, 3, clrGreen);
                 
               }
               if(OrderType() == OP_SELL && Ask <= tp) {
                  OrderClose(OrderTicket(), OrderLots(), Ask, 3, clrGreen);
               
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

void OpenMartingale() {
   int value = 0;
   int martingaleLevel = 0;

   for(int i=OrdersTotal()-1; i>=0; i--) {
      if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_OPEN)) {
         if(OrderMagicNumber() == magic && OrderSymbol() == Symbol()) {
            value++;
            if(OrderComment() == "martingale buy" || OrderComment() == "martingale sell") {
               martingaleLevel++;
            }
         }
      }
   }

   if(martingaleLevel >= 3) {
      Print("Maximum Martingale level reached. No new Martingale orders will be placed.");
      return;
   }

   if(value == 0) {
      for(int i=OrdersHistoryTotal()-1; i>=0; i--) {
         if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_HISTORY)) {
            if(OrderMagicNumber() == magic && OrderSymbol() == Symbol()) {
               value++;
               double barLength = High[1] - Low[1];
               if(OrderType() == OP_BUY) {
                  if(OrderOpenPrice() > OrderClosePrice()) {
                     SendOrder(Symbol(), OP_SELL, OrderLots() * multiply, Bid, 3, Bid + barLength, Bid - barLength, "martingale sell", magic, Red);
                  } else {
                     SendOrder(Symbol(), OP_BUY, lotes, Ask, 3, Ask - barLength, Ask + barLength, "martingale buy", magic, Blue);
                  }
               }
               if(OrderType() == OP_SELL) {
                  if(OrderOpenPrice() < OrderClosePrice()) {
                     SendOrder(Symbol(), OP_BUY, OrderLots() * multiply, Ask, 3, Ask - barLength, Ask + barLength, "martingale buy", magic, Blue);
                  } else {
                     SendOrder(Symbol(), OP_BUY, lotes, Ask, 3, Ask - barLength, Ask + barLength, "martingale buy", magic, Blue);
                  }
               }
               break;
            }
         }
      }
   }
   if(value == 0) {
      double barLength = High[1] - Low[1];
      SendOrder(Symbol(), OP_BUY, lotes, Ask, 3, Ask - barLength, Ask + barLength, "martingale buy", magic, Blue);
   }
}

void SendOrder(string symbol, int type, double lot, double price_s, int slippage_v, double stop_loss_v, double take_profit_v, string comment, int magic_v, color color_v) {
   int countTentative = 3;
   int tentative = 0;
   int ticket = 0;             
   while(IsConnected() && ticket < 1 && tentative <= countTentative) {
      RefreshRates();
      ticket = OrderSend(symbol, type, lot, price_s, slippage_v, stop_loss_v, take_profit_v, comment, magic_v, 0, color_v);
      Sleep(1000);            
      tentative++;
   }
}

void OnChartEvent(const int id, const long& lparam, const double& dparam, const string& sparam) {
   if(id == CHARTEVENT_OBJECT_CLICK) { 
      if(sparam == "sell_option") {
         stop_loss_v = Bid + stop_loss * Scale;
         take_profit_v = Bid - take_profit * Scale;         
         SendOrder(Symbol(), OP_SELL, lotes, Bid, 3, stop_loss_v, take_profit_v, "sell", magic + 1, Red);
      }
      if(sparam == "buy_option") {
         stop_loss_v = Ask - stop_loss * Scale;
         take_profit_v = Ask + take_profit * Scale;         
         SendOrder(Symbol(), OP_BUY, lotes, Ask, 3, stop_loss_v, take_profit_v, "buy", magic + 1, Blue);
      }
      if(sparam == "close_this_option") {
         closeOrdersSymbol();
      }
      if(sparam == "close_all_option") {
         closeOrdersAll();
      }                 
   }     
}

void closeOrdersSymbol() {
   int p;
   for(int i=OrdersTotal()-1; i>=0; i--) {
      if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_OPEN)) {
         if(OrderMagicNumber() == magic + 1 && OrderSymbol() == Symbol()) {
            if(OrderType() == OP_BUY) {
               p = OrderClose(OrderTicket(), OrderLots(), Bid, 3, clrSkyBlue);
            } else {
               p = OrderClose(OrderTicket(), OrderLots(), Ask, 3, clrPink);
            }                                 
         }
      }
   }
}

void closeOrdersAll() {
   int p;
   for(int i=OrdersTotal()-1; i>=0; i--) {
      if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_OPEN)) {
         if(OrderMagicNumber() == magic + 1) {
            if(OrderType() == OP_BUY) {
               p = OrderClose(OrderTicket(), OrderLots(), MarketInfo(OrderSymbol(), MODE_BID), 3, clrSkyBlue);
            } else {
               p = OrderClose(OrderTicket(), OrderLots(), MarketInfo(OrderSymbol(), MODE_ASK), 3, clrPink);
            }                                 
         }
      }
   }
}

double lotesMarginFree() {
   double MargRequired = MarketInfo(Symbol(), MODE_MARGINREQUIRED); // current price * 1000
   double Equity = AccountEquity();
   return NormalizeDouble(Equity / MargRequired, 1);  
}

int vol_ea() {
   y = 0; f = 0; g = 0; h = 0; k = 0; z = 0; jumlahbuy = 0; jumlahsell = 0; jumlahbuylimit = 0; jumlahselllimit = 0; jumlahsellstop = 0; jumlahbuystop = 0;

   //////////CANDLE///////
   double OPEN_3 = iOpen(Symbol(), 0, SHIFT_CANDLE);
   double OPEN_2 = iOpen(Symbol(), 0, SHIFT_CANDLE + 2);
   double OPEN_1 = iOpen(Symbol(), 0, SHIFT_CANDLE + 3);

   double CLOSE_3 = iClose(Symbol(), 0, SHIFT_CANDLE);
   double CLOSE_2 = iClose(Symbol(), 0, SHIFT_CANDLE + 2);
   double CLOSE_1 = iClose(Symbol(), 0, SHIFT_CANDLE + 3);

   ////CANDLE 1////
   double BULLISH = CLOSE_3 > OPEN_3;
   double BEARISH = CLOSE_3 < OPEN_3;                      

   /////////////VOLUME//////////
   double VOLUME_3 = iVolume(Symbol(), 0, SHIFT_VOLUME);
   double VOLUME_2 = iVolume(Symbol(), 0, SHIFT_VOLUME + 1);
   double VOLUME_1 = iVolume(Symbol(), 0, SHIFT_VOLUME + 2);
   double VOLUME_0 = iVolume(Symbol(), 0, SHIFT_VOLUME + 3);
   double VOLUME_LALU = iVolume(Symbol(), 0, SHIFT_VOLUME + 4);

   double VOLUME_OP = ((VOLUME_0 < VOLUME_1) && (VOLUME_1 < VOLUME_2) && (VOLUME_2 < VOLUME_3));

   if(jumlahbuy + jumlahsell == 0) {
      if (BEARISH == true && VOLUME_OP == true) {
         return(1);
      }                 
      if (BULLISH == true && VOLUME_OP == true) {
         return(1);
      } 
   }

   return(0);
}

thanks in advance
